# Closing Excel Application Process after Excel window closing in C#

Tags: c#, excel, process, export-to-excel, excel-interop

For reporting I create an excel application, export some data to it, and make it visible for the user.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
   Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
   object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
   Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
   Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
   Excel.Range range;

   //my export code here..



  //at last excel application is shown for user
  excelApp.Visible = true;
}
```

When the user clicks the "Close" button, a dialog appears that contains ["Save", "Don't save" and "Cancel"]. In any case (save or don't save), the window closes, but the EXCEL.EXE process is live like picture in this question: [Like this picture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17777545/1534785) , because I don't close it yet.

How can I define if the user closes the viewed excel window or not? If yes, then I will quit that excel application which I created.

**Edit:** I need something like "Exit event". To define if user close window, to Quit application.

Comment: Why can't you use `excellApp.Quit()`?

Comment: When will I use that? If I will use that, file will close. I want to call it after user closing file.

Answer (score 0):

You likely are using a COM object that isn't being released properly

```
Worksheets sheets = excelApp.Worksheets;
Worksheet sheet = sheets.Open(...);

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
```

Comment: Make sure you are releasing all COM objects you are creating. Also make sure you are assigning them all to vars so you can release them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i misunderstood the question....

**Old:**
Check if the Window exists

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
...
while(true)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = (IntPtr)FindWindow(windowName, null);
    public static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
}
App.Close()
```

Comment: is windowName "Book1" for excel? (Default window title) or EXCEL