# Close Excel process after importing from datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, process

as stated above, i dont know How to close the Excel process after I imported the data from my datagridview to a xls file. The Problem is that when I save my data to a xls file, i can still see the Excel process running in the Background. If i open the same file to Import the data back into my datagridview two Excel processes are now active.

Any idea How to solve this?

Here is my Code for saving my data as a xls file:

```
private void ExportDataToExcelToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog SaveExcel = new SaveFileDialog()
        {
            Title = "Save Excel File",
            CheckPathExists = true,
            DefaultExt = "txt",
            Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls",
            FilterIndex = 1,
            RestoreDirectory = true
        };

        if (SaveExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp;        //Implementierung der Applikation, welche die Daten aus dem DataGridView in eine xls Datei schreiben kann
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);       //get_Item(1) ist essentiell, da festgelegt wird auf welchem Sheet das gespeichert wird. In diesem Falle auf Sheet 1
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;

            for (i = 0; i <= DataGridViewCell.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= DataGridViewCell.ColumnCount - 1; j++)     //Die Zeilen und Spalten vom DataGridView werden gelesen
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = DataGridViewCell[j, i];
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;       //Daten werden den Spalten und Zeilen der xls Datei hinzugefügt

                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(SaveExcel.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);     //Daten werden in einer xls Datei gespeichert
            xlWorkBook.Close(0);        //Excel Applikation wird wieder geschlossen und Prozess angehalten
            xlApp.Quit();       

            ReleaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            ReleaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            ReleaseObject(xlApp);
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closing Excel process after creating using Excel COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311411/closing-excel-process-after-creating-using-excel-com)

Comment: Pretty much but I found a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (Process closeProcess in Process.GetProcesses())      
            {
                if (closeProcess.ProcessName.Equals("EXCEL"))
                {
                    closeProcess.Kill();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

this worked for me